# How to create local variables at runtime for any keyword test in TestComplete

Tags: vbscript, runtime, testcomplete

I need to create a set of local variables at the beginning of a Keyword test and then use them later while executing the Test.
Is there any possibility to create local variables dynamically as like project variables which can be created dynamically.

```
Project.variables.<variable_name> = "project_variable_value"
```

in the similar fashion can we create any variable associated to any keyword test

```
Keywordtests.<generic_keyword_test_name>.variables.<variable_name> = "local_variable_value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this. Please see this example:

```
function Test11()
{
  if (KeywordTests.Test1.Variables.VariableExists("MyVariable") == false) {
    KeywordTests.Test1.Variables.AddVariable("MyVariable", "String");
  }
  KeywordTests.Test1.Variables.MyVariable = "test value";
  Log.Message(KeywordTests.Test1.Variables.MyVariable);
}
```

Information on the `AddVariable` method can be found in the [AddVariable Method](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/80718/) help topic.